# Parallel transport on a plane.

Tags: differential-geometry

I know covariant derivative is the orthonormal projection of a vector field restricted to a curve. In the case of a plane, covariant derivative of a vector field $w$ is the same as $\dfrac{dw}{dt}$ since derivatives lie in the plane and agree with tangent plane of the plane at each point.

Then, if covariant derivative is 0 along a curve, derivative of a vector field along a curve is also 0. Hence $w$ is constant and, is that the reason why on a plane, parallel transport is a vector translated along the curve with no rotation?

Comment: Yes, that is fine. The other thing is that the tangent space of the plane never changes as you move from point to point, so there's nothing stopping you literally from literally translating the vector from one point to another.

Comment: Great, that is an amazing approach too. Thank you as always, Ted.